# C preprocessor Literal Construction

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

My problem is as follows:

I have a string literal that is macro-ed like so

```
#define TITLE "Title"
```

But there are instances when I need to pass in a wide char variant of this string. I want to be able to pass `L"Title"` to those functions. So naturally, I set out trying to define a new macro `W_TITLE` in terms of `TITLE`.

But I have no luck, all my approaches (listed bellow) have failed. Please tell me how such magic can be accomplished.

I tried

```
#define W_TITLE L##TITLE
#define W_TITLE #L TITLE
#define W_TITLE ##L TITLE
```

But they all fail...

Comment: You might like to read here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
#define WIDEN_(exp)   L##exp
#define WIDEN(exp)    WIDEN_(exp)
#define TITLE         "Title"
#define W_TITLE       WIDEN(TITLE)
```

You need to force an expansion through an intermediate macro to get what you're looking for.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WIDEN_(exp)   L##exp
#define WIDEN(exp)    WIDEN_(exp)
#define TITLE         "Title"
#define W_TITLE       WIDEN(TITLE)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%s\n", TITLE);
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", W_TITLE);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Title
Title
```

Comment: Clever. I would have tried a similar approach, but it wasn't immediately apparent to me.