# Concatenate with name of symbolic constant

Tags: c++, macros, concatenation, constants, stringify

I'm trying to make a macro that expands a symbolic constant to a `case` statement like this:

```
// #define WM_PAINT 0x000F
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
        BIND_MSG(WM_PAINT)
        // -> case WM_PAINT: Wnd_Main_WM_PAINT (hWnd, wParam, lParam); break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I tried many things. The best working macro I got was:

```
#define BIND_MSG(msg) case (msg): Wnd_Main_##msg (hWnd, wParam, lParam); break;
```

But this macro doesn't expand to `Wnd_Main_WM_PAINT`, but to `Wnd_Main_0x000F`. When I try `Wnd_Main_ ## #msg` instead of `Wnd_Main_##msg`, I don't get `Wnd_Main_WM_PAINT`, but `Wnd_Main_`. Is there any possibility to concatenate `Wnd_Main_` with the name of the symbolic constant `WM_PAINT`?

[image: Visual Studio expands the macro to <code>Wnd_Main_0x000F</code>]

(Sorry, the Screenshot is German. Visual Studio says, that the identifier `Wnd_Main_0x000F` isn't defined.)

Comment: [I get `Wnd_Main_WM_PAINT`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab8f3818f4716db2).

Comment: Is your `WM_PAINT` defined like `#define WM_PAINT 0x000F`?

Comment: More important question "Why are you developing code that is difficult to maintain?"

Comment: Yes, it's right in the link. I used as much of your posted code as I could.

Comment: Yes, the link works, but Visual Studio continues expanding it to `Wnd_Proc_0x000F`.

Comment: AFAIK, it's standard behaviour to expand it properly and non-standard behaviour to do otherwise. Does the exact code in the link expand to that?

Comment: it sounds like `WM_PAINT` is being forced through intermediate expansion, something used as-designed for text macros [such as this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275015/c-preprocessor-literal-construction/13275048#13275048). A better question is, if you're doing this, why not just use the message crackers in [`windowsx.h`](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/286954-using-windowsxh-for-better-code-organization-and-message-cracking/)

Comment: @chris: Coliru expands it to `Wnd_Main_WM_PAINT`, Visual Studio to `Wnd_Main_0x000F`